# Serializing Model using NewtonSoft in WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, thread-safety

I am trying to serialize my model each second and push it to a server. I have set up a periodic task which executes each second. I call SendNewMessage to execute the push.
The first method call to SendNewMessage() which is called from the constructor runs fine with no exceptions or issues.

When the async task tries to call the SendNewMessage I get an exception and my application shuts down. It is the NewtonSoft code:

**String PushModelToServer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, jss);** Which fails

*Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 
'C:\Users\snovva\Source\Workspaces\HMI\HMI.ViSoft\bin\x86\Debug\HMI.ViSoft.vshost.exe'.
Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x71041771, on thread 0x2788. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.*

```
   public class Model : ModelBase
    {
        public Model ()
        {
            PeriodicTask.Run(() => 
            {
                SendNewMessage();
            }, 
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            SendNewMessage();
        }
        public void SendNewMessage()
        {
            // Send the message             
            JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jss.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
            String PushModelToServer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, jss);
            sendMessage(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PushModelToServer));

        }
}

public class PeriodicTask
{
    public static async Task Run(Action action, TimeSpan period, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(period, cancellationToken);

            if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                action();
        }
    }

    public static Task Run(Action action, TimeSpan period)
    {
        return Run(action, period, CancellationToken.None);
    }
}
```

**More Info As requested:
The call on line 10 in the constructor runs. The serialization works the first time. Since the data in the model is changing I am pushing this model every second to update server. It is the async call which fails. As time passes the data in the model will change.**

Comment: Well there must be something the the class You're trying to serialize, that makes the serializer go crazy.

Comment: I believe the OP said the call (on line 10) works, but the call on line 7 inside the lambda does not.  If the class is decorated with the right attributes, it should work fine.  Maybe the OP can clarify the example to show which call works with a comment, and maybe expand the question with more details.

Comment: @KoryGill You are correct. Which attributes should I "Decorate" it with? I have not done this before. I only want the public properties which are basicly strings, floats and boolean base types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[IgnoreDataMember]` to avoid serializing properties that should not be included.

The code below works in my application, and should hopefully help you arrive at a solution for your app.

I am hoping that the code you show above is a snippet of your real code because there are some potential issues with the 1 second timer, re-entrancy, etc.  Instead of doing this timer in the Model constructor, consider moving it to another function/class and setting up the timer/calls from an additional call you setup later...again, just some suggestions on arriving at a good pattern. Do more research here...

Here is how I get my data, what you want in your `PushModelToServer`:

```
public class BackupData
{
    public List<Vehicles> Vehicles { get; private set; }
    public List<FuelStops> FuelStops { get; private set; }

    public BackupData(List<Vehicles> vehicles, List<FuelStops> fuelStops)
    {
        Vehicles = vehicles;
        FuelStops = fuelStops;
    }

    public string ToJson(Formatting formatting = Formatting.None)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, formatting);
        return json;
    }

    public static BackupData FromJson(string jsonBackupData)
    {
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BackupData>(jsonBackupData);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of one of my classes:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{VehicleName}")]
public class Vehicles : IComparable<Vehicles>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            if (id != value) { id = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }

    private string vehicleName;
    public string VehicleName
    {
        get { return vehicleName; }
        set
        {
            if (vehicleName != value) { vehicleName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return VehicleName;
    }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public UpdateState UpdateState { get; set; }
    ....
```

And here is how I get the data so I can use it anywhere I want:

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    private void OnExecuteBackup(SettingsPage obj)
    {
#else
    private async Task<bool> OnExecuteBackup(SettingsPage obj)
    {
#endif
        var backupData = App.JournalModel.GetBackupData().ToJson(Formatting.Indented);
        ...
        await SaveBackupFile(file, backupData);
        ...


public class JournalModel
{
    ...
    public BackupData GetBackupData()
    {
        var data = new BackupData(Vehicles.ToList(), FuelStops.ToList());
        return data;
    }
    ...
```

Good luck with your project.

Comment: I used the parameter:         [JsonIgnore]
 on top of some complex objects and now it works great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there must be something the the class You're trying to serialize, that makes the serializer go crazy. Maybe instead of serializing 'this' You should try serializing an actual 'DataObject' - something that can be serialized, and doesn't contain references to Timers, tasks, ect.. ?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. It would require some work though.